# QueryChangedDiskAreas method

Tags: go, vmware

I m new to vmware and i started exploring different formats in vmdk ,snapshots and all.I m using golang as a programming language.I found out that govmomi library that supports vsphere APIs that is similar to pyvmomi .I ve created snapshots using createSnapshotTask method .But i m stuck with QuerychangedDiskAreas method that retrieves list of changed blocks.I have some doubts regarding it.Can anyone help me to clear my doubts?
This is the code to get changed blocks .

func main() {

```
ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
defer cancel()

flag.Parse()

// Parse URL from string
u, err := url.Parse(*urlFlag)
if err != nil {
    exit(err)
}

// Override username and/or password as required
processOverride(u)

// Connect and log in to ESX or vCenter
c, err := govmomi.NewClient(ctx, u, *insecureFlag)
if err != nil {
    exit(err)
}

f := find.NewFinder(c.Client, true)

// Find one and only datacenter
dc, err := f.DefaultDatacenter(ctx)
if err != nil {
    exit(err)
}

// Make future calls local to this datacenter
f.SetDatacenter(dc)

// Find datastores in datacenter
dss, err := f.DatastoreList(ctx, "*")
if err != nil {
    exit(err)
}

pc := property.DefaultCollector(c.Client)

// Convert datastores into list of references
var refs []types.ManagedObjectReference
for _, ds := range dss {
    refs = append(refs, ds.Reference())
}

// Retrieve summary property for all datastores
var dst []mo.Datastore
err = pc.Retrieve(ctx, refs, []string{"summary"}, &dst)
if err != nil {
    exit(err)
}

//get Virtual Machines
vms, err := f.VirtualMachineList(ctx, "*")
if err != nil {

}

//apps, _ := f.VirtualAppList(ctx, "")
//fmt.Println(apps[0].String())

//r.dataStore = r.f.DefaultDatastore(r.ctx, "*")
// Convert virtual machines into list of references
var vmrefs types.ManagedObjectReference
var device *types.VirtualDevice
fmt.Println(device)
var devices object.VirtualDeviceList
name := ""
for i, vm := range vms {
    name, _ = vm.Name(ctx)
    if name == "Ubuntu Target" {
        fmt.Println(name)
        devices, _ = vm.Device(ctx)
        device = devices[i].GetVirtualDevice()

        vmrefs = vm.Common.Reference()

        break
    }

}

req := new(types.CreateSnapshot_Task)
req.Description = "Snapshot created  by Data Migration Tool."
req.Name = "Ubuntu Target"
req.Memory = false

req.This.Type = vmrefs.Type
req.This.Value = vmrefs.Value
s, e := methods.CreateSnapshot_Task(ctx, c.RoundTripper, req)
if e != nil {
    fmt.Println(e)

}

time.Sleep(time.Second * 3)

queryReq := new(types.QueryChangedDiskAreas)
queryReq.ChangeId = "*"
queryReq.DeviceKey = device.Key
queryReq.Snapshot = new(types.ManagedObjectReference)
queryReq.Snapshot.Type = s.Returnval.Type
queryReq.Snapshot.Value = s.Returnval.Value
queryReq.StartOffset = 0

queryReq.This.Type =vmrefs.Type
queryReq.This.Value= =vmrefs.Value
_, e = methods.QueryChangedDiskAreas(ctx, c.RoundTripper, queryReq)

if e != nil {
    fmt.Println("error in query", e.Error())
}
```

}

Can you please tell if i am missing anything?

Comment: What doubts do you have?

Comment: The QueryChangedDiskAreas method takes req as one of the arguments.req is of types.QueryChangedDiskAreas type.I tried to assign virtual machine reference to req.this .But i am getting  The request refers to an unexpected or unknown type error.am i doing it wrongly?

Comment: I suggest linking to the documentation about what you're worried about, and to try to explain as clearly as possible why you're worried about it.

Comment: I posted the code that i have.Can you please have a look at it?

Comment: You posted it in the wrong location. You posted it as an answer, but it is not an answer. Please edit your code into your question instead. (Use the 'edit' link on your original question.)

Comment: Sorry .I have edited now